# How to get 2 resultset in linq in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have doing Development in MVC. and I have written SQL store procedure which returns count of table and table data  and i want to get that result-sets in LINQ using MVC.

When I Tried to do the same I didn't get record count of table.
Please let us know any way.....

I have below data getting from sql server database.

First Resultset
RowCount
4

Second Resultset
ID  FileName  FileDescription
1     OD           OD
2     pastDue      pastDue
3     SCMS           SCMS
4     FailTrade      FailTrade

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but I'm going tot assume that you load all of your data into a List of your object (probably called File).

```
List<File> Files = ... ;
```

For your first resultset you probably won't need LINQ because you can simply use: `Files.Count()` to know how many records your resultset returned.

It seems your second resultset is already what you want so you won't need any LINQ for that either.